# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.3:attached-rpm

Tags: windows, maven, cygwin, rpm

I'm trying to build a rpm on **Windows** with cygwin64 and maven, and I'm getting this error when try to build

```
RPM build errors:
error: installed files were found (but unpacked):
/etc/httpd/conf.d/jk-instances-8080/myApp.conf
[INFO]    /etc/httpd/conf.d/jk-instances-8080/myApp.properties
[INFO]    /etc/sysconfig/myApp
[INFO]    /software/myApp/conf/Catalina/localhost/myApp.xml
[INFO]    /software/myApp/conf/catalina.policy
[INFO]    /software/myApp/conf/catalina.properties
[INFO]    /software/myApp/conf/context.xml
[INFO]    /software/myApp/conf/server.xml
[INFO]    /software/myApp/conf/tomcat-users.xml
[INFO]    /software/myApp/conf/web.xml
[INFO]     File listed twice: /config/unified
[INFO]     File listed twice: /config/unified/myAppAdminConfiguration
[INFO]     File listed twice: /config/unified/myAppAdminConfiguration/configuration.properties
[INFO]     File listed twice: /config/unified/myApp.controllers.auth.FileBasedAuthControllerConfig
[INFO]     File listed twice: /config/unified/myApp.controllers.auth.FileBasedAuthControllerConfig/configuration.properties

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45.353 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-12T18:32:14-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 51M/717M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.3:attached-rpm (build-rpm) on project myApp: RPM build execution returned: '1' executing 'cmd.exe /X /C "rpmbuild -bb --target x86_64-myApp-linux --buildroot /cygdrive/C/cygwin64/home/NB039/workspace/myApp/myApp/target/rpm/myApp/buildroot --define "_topdir /cygdrive/C/cygwin64/home/NB039/workspace/myApp/myApp/target/rpm/myApp" myApp.spec"' -> [Help 1]
```

Any Help?